# Compare scores of models

Tags: xgboost, probability-calibration, score

We got several models with predictions. How can we compare scores of different models with each other?

We assume that we got xgboost models and scores distribution can be different for each model, so how can we compare scores?

Comment: You have various models and you want to compare their scores? But you already have the scores, so the metric has already been chosen and the score calculated. Is that right? If so, you have one score per trained model. How many models do you have (that you need some method to compare scores, which are just numbers) and what exactly do you mean by comparing them?

Comment: @89f3a1c, OP: or do you mean the scores given to each sample?

Comment: scores for each model can be distributed differently so you can't really say that 0.8 in one model means he is more likely to buy then if he has 0.78 in other model

Comment: You've used the probability-calibration tag, so presumably you know a little about the standard methods for that?

Comment: This question could be improved by helping us understand what specific kind of comparison you're looking for.

Comment: as i get standart methods will fit from scratch and i just want to calibrate scores of different models to probabilities

Comment: For example, are you looking for a summary metric about the predictions, an understanding of how the prediction distribution varies over some dataset, or something else?

Comment: one person can buy product 1 with score 0.8(model 1 xgb score) and other product with score 0.799(model 2 xgb score) i can offer only one product, which should i choose? so i want to convert scores to probability or to one scale and then compare. I can't offer multiclass in this case

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your using python and scikit-learn mostly because it has a method for providing model metrics.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# I presume that you've already trained a model and it's saved as xgb
# X_test is your testing X data (NOT THE DATA YOU TRAINED ON!!!!)
# Y_test is the corresponding correct values
print('Accuracy score is: ',accuracy_score(Y_test, xgb.predict(X_test)) * 100)
print(classification_report(Y_test, xgb.predict(X_test)))
>>> Accuracy score is:  61.13989637305699
>>>           precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.38      0.98      0.55        47
           1       0.99      0.49      0.66       146

   micro avg       0.61      0.61      0.61       193
   macro avg       0.68      0.74      0.60       193
weighted avg       0.84      0.61      0.63       193
```

As you can see there is lots of info available.
The accuracy score is the % of correct predictions overall.
And the classification report goes into more depth about how good the model is predicting each class more info here [crossvalidated SE explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117654/what-does-the-numbers-in-the-classification-report-of-sklearn-mean).

Comment: i have already trained 10 models(binary if he buy product1 or not. each model for each product not multiclass) now i have different distributions in scores that xgb returns. so i can't say for sure that if for product 1 person has score 0.8 he will more likely buy 1 product then product 2 where he has score 0.78

Comment: Why do you want to only have binary models? What are you actually trying to predict?

Comment: i want to predict if someone will buy a product. i have xgb scores as result. And i want to compare several models to see what product is more preferable

Comment: Ok so if your only trying to predict which product someone will buy, why do you need multiple models?

Comment: because for each product i have different batches of people that can intersect and these models can be calculated in different time periods

Comment: Ok just read your comment on the original question. In my the precision is the number of true positives (i.e how many of the predicted values for that class where correct) and recall is how many of that class where correctly predicted. Your algorithim will either return yes or no for each individual product and you want to know if you have two answers which one you should trust more. I would advise you pickle each of your models then run them in order on the input (highest accuracy/recall first). And stop at the first positives identification. However it would be better if you could multiclass

Comment: original question is more about if i got two xgb scores(not class but 'proba') of 2 different models, how can i compare them if we know that we can't really say that xgb returns real probability

Answer (score 1):

You included that `probability-calibration` tag, which is prescient: there are a few techniques, all called "probability calibration," which adjust the scores output by a model to better fit observed probabilities.  After this, the scores should be close to representing real probabilities, and should therefore be directly comparable.

The most common methods are Platt scaling and isotonic regression.  There is a third and more recent method, beta calibration, and there are a few more exotic ones around.  The three ones I've named all fit to a new dataset a univariate function with inputs your model's scores and outputs the actual observed labels.  Platt scaling fits a sigmoid function, beta calibration fits a parametric model that is more general than sigmoid, and isotonic fits a nonparametric, arbitrary non-decreasing function.  XGBoost's outputs are biased away from 0 and 1, so the sigmoid is generally ill-suited, so in this case go with beta or isotonic (or find something else to your liking).  Isotonic, being more well-known, has more open-source implementations.